# Config Glide library for caching

Tags: java, android, android-glide

How to set glide in the android project so that once images download to the app each time then displayed by the glide cache

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Please go through 
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html

Comment: as i remember, caching in Glide work by default and you can customize, learn more about it using the link that @KishanMaurya provided

Comment: add line `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your Glide object by providing the request options and that's it. Glide will take care of caching for you. Happy coding with Glide "A simple and feature rich image loading library."

```
val requestOptions = RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
Glide.with(context).load(url).apply(requestOptions).into(imageView)
```